# Getting error when running subroutine in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran, fortran95

I have these as part of a program to run linear integration, here's my function and subroutine that's part of the problem

```
SUBROUTINE interpol(x,f,xd,fd)
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL::linterp
EXTERNAL linterp
REAL,DIMENSION(5)::x
REAL,DIMENSION(5)::f
REAL,DIMENSION(9)::xd
REAL (KIND=8),DIMENSION(9),INTENT(OUT)::fd
INTEGER::i,j
DO i=1, 9
    DO j=1, 5
        IF (x(j) <  xd(i) .AND. xd(i) <=  x(j+1)) THEN
        fd(i)=linterp(x(j),f(j),xd(j))
        END IF
    END DO
END DO
END SUBROUTINE interpol

FUNCTION linterp(xd,x,f)
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL,DIMENSION(5)::xd
REAL,DIMENSION(5)::linterp
REAL,DIMENSION(5)::x
REAL,DIMENSION(5)::f
INTEGER::j,i
linterp=f(i)+((x-x(i)))/(x(i+1)-x(i))*(f(i+1)-f(i))
END FUNCTION linterp
```

When I run it I can't get rid of this error

```
lin.f90:26:0:

 linterp=f(i)+((x-x(i)))/(x(i+1)-x(i))*(f(i+1)-f(i))
 1
Error: Different shape for array assignment at (1) on dimension 1 (9 and 5)
lin.f90:3:13:

 REAL::linterp
             1
Error: Explicit interface required for ‘linterp’ at (1): array result
```

I understand the error code but I just can't see where I'm going wrong, can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: i'm trying my best to understand all this but I am pretty new to it, please have patience.

Comment: Don't change the question that much! It makes the answers very confusing...

Comment: To the new question: don't define the function result as an array. It is not  what is calculated, and further complicates matters. A simple `real function ...` suffices. If you feel posh, you can define `linterp` explicitly, but please remove the `,DIMENSION(5)`.

Comment: are you getting the error while compiling or while running?

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `linterp` as an array!

```
REAL,DIMENSION(9)::linterp
```

It should be the (scalar) function:

```
REAL :: linterp
EXTERNAL linterp
```

---

You also need to specify more arguments for `linterp`:

```
        fd(i)=linterp( x(j), x(j+1), f(j), f(j+1), xx(i) )
```

Comment: I've changed the definition of linter like you said but I'm still getting this error:

'lin.f90:3:13:

 REAL::linterp
             1
Error: Explicit interface required for ‘linterp’ at (1): array result'

Comment: @captainlh56 You probably did not do the changes you were suggested. The error probably comes from the fact you still try to return an array and not a scalar.